# Regex for text between two static strings

Tags: regex, vba, email, outlook, special-characters

I'm trying to extract text from a series of e-mails. These mails look like:

> Hello,
>
> bla bla bla. The reason for this is: the problem was resolved after
>   all
>
> Kind regards,
>
> bla bla

I've got a regular expression like this:

```
With ReasonReg
    .Pattern = "(The reason for this is\s*:\s*)(\w\s*)+(?=\s*Kind regards)"
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = False
End With
```

My problem arises with mails where digits and special characters (colons and question marks) are used. \w doesn't match those, of course, but if I try any of the following, my Outlook (Office 365) becomes unresponsive.

```
.Pattern = "(The reason for this is\s*:\s*)(.*\s*)+(?=\s*Kind regards)"
.Pattern = "(The reason for this is\s*:\s*)(\w\W*\s*)+(?=\s*Kind regards)"
.Pattern = "(The reason for this is\s*:\s*)(\w[:?]*\s*)+(?=\s*Kind regards)"
```

Comment: Try `.Pattern = "(The reason for this is\s*:\s*)([\s\S]*?)(\s*Kind regards)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to match everything between `The reason for this is\s*:\s*` and `Kind regards`.

You can use a `[\s\S]` construct to match any character, and apply a lazy quantifier to it (`*?`) to match as few chars as possible before the first `Kind regards`:

```
.Pattern = "(The reason for this is\s*:\s*)([\s\S]*?)(\s*Kind regards)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP2yR0/1)

If there are huge texts to match between these delimiters, consider unrolling the lazy matching construct, e.g.:

```
(The reason for this is\s*:\s*)(\S*(?:\s(?!\s*Kind regards)\S+)*)(\s*Kind regards)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP2yR0/2). This `\S*(?:\s(?!\s*Kind regards)\S+)*` pattern matches 0+ non-whitespace chars (`\S*`) that are followed with 0+ sequences of 1+ whitespaces not followed with `Kind regards` and 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Comment: Even though a regex will work, it's going to be faster to use a combination of `InStr()` and `Mid()` for this task. Should not be too hard to do since the delimiters are plain fixed strings and not actually patterns.

Comment: I have written a general [article about extracting strings between two strings with regex](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/extracting-text-two-strings-regular-expressions), too, feel free to read if you have a problem approaching your current similar problem.